# LoginManager in Xamarin iOS SDK doesn't cache AccessTokens

Tags: ios, facebook, xamarin

I'm trying to use Xamarin native iOS library to authenticate with Facebook and access Graph API.

According to release 4.0.1.1 notes for the component (I didn't find any other documentation anywhere)

> FBSDKTokenCachingStrategy. No alternative. **LoginManager class caches
>   tokens to keychain automatically.** You can observe token changes to do
>   manual post processing.

However this doesn't seem to be happening. When my iOS application starts I create LoginManager instance and call Init. However after that AccessToken.CurrentAccessToken is still null. It is only populated with data after I call LogInWithReadPermissionsAsync on the LoginManager.

Am I missing something or is it a bug.

Here's my code.

```
   public bool IsLoggedIn
    {
        get
        {
            return AccessToken.CurrentAccessToken != null &&
                  AccessToken.CurrentAccessToken.ExpirationDate.ToDateTime() > DateTime.Now;
        }
    }
    public Task<AccessToken> FacebookLoginInternal()
    {
        lock (monitor)
        {
            if (_loginTask == null)
            {
                LoginManager manager = new LoginManager();
                manager.Init();

                if (IsLoggedIn)
                {
                    var ts = new TaskCompletionSource<AccessToken>();
                    ts.SetResult(AccessToken.CurrentAccessToken);
                    _loginTask = ts.Task;
                }
                else
                {
                    var loginResult = manager.LogInWithReadPermissionsAsync(
                        new string[] { "email", "user_friends" });

                    _loginTask = loginResult.ContinueWith(r =>
                    {
                        return r.Result.Token;
                    });
                }
            }

            return _loginTask;
        }
```

Comment: When you call LogInWithReadPermissionsAsync for the second time, the accessToken is the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per response from Xamarin support (thank you!)

The following code fixes the issue:

```
public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
    {
        return ApplicationDelegate.SharedInstance.FinishedLaunching(app, options);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This would seem to be expected behavior? You won't have a token until you log in, and this seems expected. I believe you may have misunderstood the note you pasted. It does not say that the token is cached as soon as you instantiate LoginManager or call Init on it, just that LoginManager will cache the token. It can't cache a token until a token is generated when you log in. That is why (I believe) [Guilherme Torres Castro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1107651/guilherme-torres-castro) asked if the token is the same after a second call to LogInWithReadPermissionsAsync. If so, then the token was cached upon login.

**Update:** Communication with the OP via other channels indicates that I misunderstood. Log in is not maintained after app termination and relaunch, whereas in the native Obj-C Facebook iOS SDK it is. A bug has been filed: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=30287